# Restore phone and keep whatsapp number after changing sim

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I am going to restore my phone and I want to keep my whatsapp number.
The thing  is, after restoring I am going to use a new number. 
Restoring my phone means I will have to reinstall whatsapp, then I will be asked to verify phone number. My old SIM is not working anymore.
What should I do to keep my old whatsapp number?

I am using samsung galaxy nexus android version 4.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Insert the new SIM into the phone.

Go to Whatsapp settings > Account > Change number

Validate the new number.

Go to Chat settings > Backup conversations

Follow the instructions [here](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/20902622) to restore the conversations

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Backup your WhatsApp from old phone using [Helium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup). Follow the
  instructions for backing up WhatsApp (or any other application for
  that matter).
- Once the backup is complete, you'll find a folder named "Carbon" on
  your phone storage.
- Copy this folder on your PC.
- Install Helium on the phone after restoring and get this backed up folder on your
  phone and place on the same location on the storage.
- Start Helium and backup WhatsApp using the "Restore and Sync" tab
  available in the app.

If you are not rooted, you need to connect your phone to PC using USB cable to start the backup. Follow the instructions given on Play Store page.